# Laravel Limit Client Download Speed (Bandwidth throttling)

Tags: laravel, bandwidth, bandwidth-throttling, download-speed

In Laravel, I can download using

> response()->download();

But is there any way to limit client speed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package:

> https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle

**Installation**

```
composer require bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle
```

***This example will stream a video with a rate of 100KiB/s to the browser:***

```
use bandwidthThrottle\BandwidthThrottle;

$in  = fopen(__DIR__ . "/video.mpg", "r");
$out = fopen("php://output", "w");

$throttle = new BandwidthThrottle();
$throttle->setRate(100, BandwidthThrottle::KIBIBYTES); // Set limit to 100KiB/s
$throttle->throttle($out);

stream_copy_to_stream($in, $out);
```

Comment: No longer maintained since 2017. It's a shame that there seems to be no way doing that in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

No as far as i know, you can't limit the download speed via script.